# xlswrite is giving some error while using "for loop" in matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I need to write the output of each loop in the same excel sheet, column-wise.

'Y' output data in column-A of excel sheet and 'Theta_3' output data in column-B of the same sheet.

In the next loop, output must be written in C and D column, and so on.....

Each loop gives either 4 or 8 real roots of the polynomial (defined in 'r'). I dont want imaginary roots. So, interested in 8 real roots only.

I have written code for this.

But, its showing the following error:

> Error using xlswrite (line 166) Input data must be a numeric, cell, or
>   logical array.

```
clear all
clc
syms y real
format short
  for l3 = 0.77:.01:1.06;
    l1 = sqrt(2);
    l2 = sqrt(2);
    r=4096 * l1 .^ 8 * y .^ 8 - 32768 * l1 .^ 7 * l3 * y .^ 8 - 16384 * l1 .^ 6 * l2 .^ 2 * y .^ 8 + 147456 * l1 .^ 6 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 8 + 131072 * l1 .^ 5 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 * y .^ 8 - 425984 * l1 .^ 5 * l3 .^ 3 * y .^ 8 + 32768 * l1 .^ 4 * l2 .^ 4 * y .^ 8 - 491520 * l1 .^ 4 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 8 + 876544 * l1 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 4 * y .^ 8 - 262144 * l1 .^ 3 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 * y .^ 8 + 1114112 * l1 .^ 3 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 3 * y .^ 8 - 1277952 * l1 .^ 3 * l3 .^ 5 * y .^ 8 - 65536 * l1 .^ 2 * l2 .^ 6 * y .^ 8 + 655360 * l1 .^ 2 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 8 - 1589248 * l1 .^ 2 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 4 * y .^ 8 + 1327104 * l1 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 6 * y .^ 8 + 262144 * l1 * l2 .^ 6 * l3 * y .^ 8 - 917504 * l1 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 3 * y .^ 8 + 1376256 * l1 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 5 * y .^ 8 - 884736 * l1 * l3 .^ 7 * y .^ 8 + 65536 * l2 .^ 8 * y .^ 8 - 262144 * l2 .^ 6 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 8 + 491520 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 4 * y .^ 8 - 589824 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 6 * y .^ 8 + 331776 * l3 .^ 8 * y .^ 8 + 16384 * l1 .^ 8 * y .^ 6 - 65536 * l1 .^ 7 * l3 * y .^ 6 - 65536 * l1 .^ 6 * l2 .^ 2 * y .^ 6 - 65536 * l1 .^ 6 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 6 + 262144 * l1 .^ 5 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 * y .^ 6 + 720896 * l1 .^ 5 * l3 .^ 3 * y .^ 6 + 131072 * l1 .^ 4 * l2 .^ 4 * y .^ 6 - 131072 * l1 .^ 4 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 6 - 1998848 * l1 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 4 * y .^ 6 - 524288 * l1 .^ 3 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 * y .^ 6 - 917504 * l1 .^ 3 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 3 * y .^ 6 + 2162688 * l1 .^ 3 * l3 .^ 5 * y .^ 6 - 262144 * l1 .^ 2 * l2 .^ 6 * y .^ 6 + 524288 * l1 .^ 2 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 6 - 65536 * l1 .^ 2 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 4 * y .^ 6 - 589824 * l1 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 6 * y .^ 6 + 524288 * l1 * l2 .^ 6 * l3 * y .^ 6 - 1835008 * l1 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 3 * y .^ 6 + 2752512 * l1 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 5 * y .^ 6 - 1769472 * l1 * l3 .^ 7 * y .^ 6 + 262144 * l2 .^ 8 * y .^ 6 - 1048576 * l2 .^ 6 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 6 + 1966080 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 4 * y .^ 6 - 2359296 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 6 * y .^ 6 + 1327104 * l3 .^ 8 * y .^ 6 + 24576 * l1 .^ 8 * y .^ 4 - 98304 * l1 .^ 6 * l2 .^ 2 * y .^ 4 - 425984 * l1 .^ 6 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 4 + 196608 * l1 .^ 4 * l2 .^ 4 * y .^ 4 + 720896 * l1 .^ 4 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 4 + 3686400 * l1 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 4 * y .^ 4 - 393216 * l1 .^ 2 * l2 .^ 6 * y .^ 4 - 262144 * l1 .^ 2 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 4 + 3047424 * l1 .^ 2 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 4 * y .^ 4 - 3833856 * l1 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 6 * y .^ 4 + 393216 * l2 .^ 8 * y .^ 4 - 1572864 * l2 .^ 6 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 4 + 2949120 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 4 * y .^ 4 - 3538944 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 6 * y .^ 4 + 1990656 * l3 .^ 8 * y .^ 4 + 16384 * l1 .^ 8 * y .^ 2 + 65536 * l1 .^ 7 * l3 * y .^ 2 - 65536 * l1 .^ 6 * l2 .^ 2 * y .^ 2 - 65536 * l1 .^ 6 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 2 - 262144 * l1 .^ 5 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 * y .^ 2 - 720896 * l1 .^ 5 * l3 .^ 3 * y .^ 2 + 131072 * l1 .^ 4 * l2 .^ 4 * y .^ 2 - 131072 * l1 .^ 4 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 2 - 1998848 * l1 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 4 * y .^ 2 + 524288 * l1 .^ 3 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 * y .^ 2 + 917504 * l1 .^ 3 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 3 * y .^ 2 - 2162688 * l1 .^ 3 * l3 .^ 5 * y .^ 2 - 262144 * l1 .^ 2 * l2 .^ 6 * y .^ 2 + 524288 * l1 .^ 2 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 2 - 65536 * l1 .^ 2 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 4 * y .^ 2 - 589824 * l1 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 6 * y .^ 2 - 524288 * l1 * l2 .^ 6 * l3 * y .^ 2 + 1835008 * l1 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 3 * y .^ 2 - 2752512 * l1 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 5 * y .^ 2 + 1769472 * l1 * l3 .^ 7 * y .^ 2 + 262144 * l2 .^ 8 * y .^ 2 - 1048576 * l2 .^ 6 * l3 .^ 2 * y .^ 2 + 1966080 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 4 * y .^ 2 - 2359296 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 6 * y .^ 2 + 1327104 * l3 .^ 8 * y .^ 2 + 4096 * l1 .^ 8 + 32768 * l1 .^ 7 * l3 - 16384 * l1 .^ 6 * l2 .^ 2 + 147456 * l1 .^ 6 * l3 .^ 2 - 131072 * l1 .^ 5 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 + 425984 * l1 .^ 5 * l3 .^ 3 + 32768 * l1 .^ 4 * l2 .^ 4 - 491520 * l1 .^ 4 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 2 + 876544 * l1 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 4 + 262144 * l1 .^ 3 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 - 1114112 * l1 .^ 3 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 3 + 1277952 * l1 .^ 3 * l3 .^ 5 - 65536 * l1 .^ 2 * l2 .^ 6 + 655360 * l1 .^ 2 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 2 - 1589248 * l1 .^ 2 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 4 + 1327104 * l1 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 6 - 262144 * l1 * l2 .^ 6 * l3 + 917504 * l1 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 3 - 1376256 * l1 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 5 + 884736 * l1 * l3 .^ 7 + 65536 * l2 .^ 8 - 262144 * l2 .^ 6 * l3 .^ 2 + 491520 * l2 .^ 4 * l3 .^ 4 - 589824 * l2 .^ 2 * l3 .^ 6 + 331776 * l3 .^ 8;
[Y]=(solve(r));
[theta_3]=double(atan(Y)*2*180/pi);
mainArrayToWrite = [Y.', theta_3.']
filename = 'data.xlsx';
sheet = 1;
xlRange = 'A1';
xlswrite(filename, mainArrayToWrite, sheet, xlRange)
  end
%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: The error states clearly that you must pass in numeric, cell or logical data. You are trying to pass in an array of sym objects... You've also asked Matlab to solve an expression, i.e. not an equation which is equal to anything.

Comment: Error using xlswrite (line 220) Error: The server threw an exception.

Use this to covert to numeri out:

    [out] = [Y', double(double(theta_3))'];

Comment: Error using xlswrite (line 220) Error: The server threw an exception.

I have used the following code to covert the sym to numeric output, But, its displaying the above error.

    [out] = [Y', double(double(theta_3))'];

Comment: Y is symbolic, i don't even know if theta_3 is, and you  can't just cast a symbolic variable to a double anyway, they are fundamentally different. I suggest you try and understand more about symbolic variables, and look at the variable types in your workspace